# How to fetch files from a folder in Amazon EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

How to access a folder and get its files from Amazon EBS through a .NET Core application where I only know the path to the folder?

Comment: Didn't you or one of your friends ask this exact same question an hour ago (with just as little information)? please read [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Can you please help me

Comment: @Sam If you want us to help you, you should read up on the how to ask link from the first comment. You have to share your code (or at least some minimal example) and what you have tried so far. Otherwise we will most likely not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EBS is a virtual disk attached to an Amazon EC2 instance.

From within the EC2 instance, it looks just like a local disk. Therefore, reference it just like you do a normal disk (eg C: Drive on Windows or full path in Linux). The fact that it is using Amazon EBS is irrelevant to your C# program.

Comment: Thanks. Anyways but this gave me an idea. How do i get full linux path, and how the access the Amazon EWS

Comment: Amazon EBS volumes can only be accessed when they are **attached to an Amazon EC2 instance**. It's just a storage drive. Access it how you would normally access data on disk.